# Xcode 5 Header file not found?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, build, xcode5

I'm new to iOS development, and downloaded a sample project to play with.

The project itself required a the GMGridView library which was NOT included with the download.

So i downloaded the library separately, added the reference ".xcodeproj" to it and crossed my finger and prayed that it'll work.

Obviously it didn't, that's why i'm here.

The error i keep getting is this `GMGridView/GMGridView.h` file not found.

The file header IS there,

Things that I tried before screaming for help:

- added "GMGridView.xcodeproj" in "BuildPhase" -> "Target Dependencies" of Z-way project.
- ensured the Search Path has `GMGridView`, i set it to recursive, as well as tried both relative and absolute path. no luck.

What else could be the reason, I'm totally stumped?

[image: File Structure]

Answer (score 2):

Another possible cause:

Make sure you don't have a duplicated header (that is hidden somewhere in the folder) that has a wrong path(missing to xcode).

Answer (score 2):

`"Always Search User Path"` in `Build Setting` - Set it to "Yes".

Also Try with

`"Target Dependencies"` in `Build Phases` - Add your dependent project here.

Answer (score 0):

What about under Build Phases -> Link Binary with Libraries -> + ??? try to see if you can find it there..

Comment: It just have the default ones (i believe they are default at least, coreData.framework/QuartzCore/UIKit/Foundation/CoreGrahpics...

It doesn't have any reference to the subproject though... should there be?